# iterating through for loop and if condition not satisfied do something. python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have following condition:

```
a=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i==j:
            a.append(i)
```

I want to add a statement `a.append(np.nan)` if i!=j after looping through list2.
i.e
After iterating through inner for loop, if i don't find any i==j then it should append `nan`.
PS.: I have such lists that there will be at-most once `i==j`.

How to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to find the intersection of two lists? Please don't do it like this.

Comment: I'd recommend something like this: `set2 = set(list2); 
a = [i if i in set2 else 'nan' for i in list1]`

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [2,1,3,5]
a = [i if i in list2 else np.nan for i in list1]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, nan]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with list comprehension.

`a = [i if j == i else np.nan for i in list1 for j in list2]`

First we assign i if i==j if it is not we assign np.nan.
Then we iterate on list1 for i
and list 2 for j

Answer (score -1):

After the if statement of `i==j` just return another condition after your if statement but on the same indent as your if statement, if will perform that operation in case your if statement is false.

```
a=[]
for i in list1:
   for j in list2:
      if i==j:
          a.append(i)  
      a.append(np.nan)
```

Comment: You cant do `return` outside a function or method

Comment: My bad, it wasn't supposed to be a return but rather an append to list in case `i==j` fails.

Comment: But that will append man to the list every time through the loop, which isn’t what is needed is it ?